# Non-noetherian coherent local rings

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, galois-representations, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a non-neotherian UFD such that $A$ satisfies the following condition $(\sharp)$$\colon$

$(\sharp)$ For any prime ideal ${\frak P}$ of $A$ such that ${\mathrm{ht}}({\frak P}) < \infty$, the localisation $A_{\frak P}$ at ${\frak P}$ is a regular local ring.

### Q. Is A necessarily coherent?

Comment: The question as written is confusing. 1) A regular local ring is noetherian by definition. Do you use a different definition of regularity? 2) What else than ${\rm ht}(\mathfrak{P})$ could the Krull dimension of $A_{\mathfrak{P}}$ possibly be?